# Fading in multiple classes one after another, (background image) slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a background slider for a wordpress website. It is a full width slider, and it has four slides. What I've done is create 4 separate classes for each image, and I'm trying to `fadeIn` each class, one after another, after a 5 second interval.

I'm new at this, so my code is NOT best practice I'm sure, and frankly it's not even working. But here it is, I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions as to what else I could do.

```
if(jQuery(".background").hasClass('image-1')){
    jQuery('.image-1').fadeOut(5000, function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('image-1');
    });
    jQuery('image-2').fadeIn(5000, function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('image-2');
    });
}else if(jQuery('.background').hasClass('image-2')){
    jQuery('.image-').fadeOut(5000, function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('image-2');
    });
    jQuery('image-3').fadeIn(5000, function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('image-3');
    });
}else if(jQuery('.background').hasClass('image-3')){
    jQuery('.image-').fadeOut(5000, function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('image-3');
    });
    jQuery('image-4').fadeIn(5000, function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('image-4');
    });
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpsumner1289/p0uswpcy/2/)

Comment: I am not saying this is the only problem but a quick glance shows removeCLass which should be removeClass (lowercase 'l')

Comment: Thanks! It didn't fix the issue but I probably would have never noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but try

```
$('.background').addClass('image-3');

var bg = $(".background");

if ( bg.hasClass('image-1') ){
    $('.image-1').fadeOut(5000, function() {
        bg.removeClass('image-1').addClass('image-2');
        $('.image-2').fadeIn(5000);
    });
} else if ( bg.hasClass('image-2') ) {
    $('.image-2').fadeOut(5000, function() {
        bg.removeClass('image-2').addClass('image-3');
        $('.image-3').fadeIn(5000);
    });
} else if (bg.hasClass('image-3')) {
    $('.image-3').fadeOut(5000, function() {
        bg.removeClass('image-3').addClass('image-4');
        $('.image-4').fadeIn(5000);
    });
}
```

Comment: So this worked to fade out the initial image, but nothing else worked after that. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpsumner1289/p0uswpcy/3/

Answer (score 0):

instead of multiple if and else statement you can use each loop in jquery
Here is the sample code. THis may help you.

```
var i =1;
jQuery(".background").each(function(){
  if(jQuery(this).hasClass('image-'+i)){
    jQuery('.image-'+i).fadeOut(5000, function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('image-'+i);
    });
    jQuery('image-'+(i+1)).fadeIn(5000, function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('image-'+(i+1));
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Now it fades out the first image but never fades in the next

Comment: i have update code. try to do some thing like : (5000*i)

Comment: Still nothing. Wouldn't adding the * operator just make the fade in run for 5 seconds times whatever number the image class was?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a better way it with the help of a friend. Made three divs, created this code to fade them in and out in 3 second intervals.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var imgcnt = 3;
        var curimage = 1;

        imageinterval = setInterval(function() {
            var newimg;
            if (curimage == imgcnt) newimg = 1;
            else newimg = curimage + 1;

            $("#image" + curimage).fadeToggle(1000);
            $("#image" + newimg).fadeToggle(1000);
            curimage = newimg;

        }, 3000);
    });
```